# How can I convert a hash representation in an escaped string to an actual hash?

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a field stored in a MySQL db that is a string, but it is storing a representation of a hash. I'm wondering how I could convert this string into a hash. I have tried a bunch of different things with gsub and JSON.parse to no avail.

Here is a reference to what I'm trying to convert:

```rb
=> "{:address=>\"\", :city=>\"\", :country=>\"\", :zip=>\"\", :state=>\"\", :industry=>\"\", :org=>\"\", :job_title=>\"\", :purchasing_time_frame=>\"\", :role_in_purchase_process=>\"\", :no_of_employees=>\"\", :comments=>\"\", :custom_questions=>[{\"title\"=>\"License Number\", \"value\"=>\"345g3245\"}, {\"title\"=>\"License Type\", \"value\"=>\"Legal\"}], :create_time=>\"2022-01-17T22:49:26Z\"}"
```

Comment: How much do you trust that string? Can you fix things up to use a JSON column or at least a string of JSON? You'd still have to deal with all the existing data but at least things would be less painful in the future.

Comment: @muistooshort it can take in data from a public place so not really at all. It is getting the string from an API call. Idk why the original programmer set it up this way tbh. Also, if i puts this, the slashes aren't there. So, I guess it's not actually escaped. I was trying to gsub it to be compatible with JSON.parse but my regex is terrible and had to take a break :P

Comment: What were your gsub expressions?  Did they look something like `.gsub(/(, |{|\[):(\\\")?([^=\\]*|=[^>]*)(\\\")?=>/ , '\1"\3":').gsub(/("[^"]*")=>("[^"]*")/ , '\1:\2')`?  I'm not sure of how the ruby json parser works, but some json parsers expect stringed keys.

Comment: @entitycs that gsub worked perfectly!

Comment: @NolanMayersky Nice. I can tell you that what I provided is not very robust, so I wouldn't offer it as a final solution.  I just used the RegExr website to whip something up as a proof of concept.  All that code seeks to do is 1) replace :key=> with "key":, (whether or not key is quoted) and 2) replace the obvious/intentional cases 1) misses, which is when the key doesn't start with a colon, and already has quotation marks.  A better solution exists - one that uses the allowed Ruby Hash syntax in all its forms, and can be written in one elegant pattern, but it's a start.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON object. It should be: 1) generated to represent as an array of objects since there are two of them, and 2) be serialized with string keys unless you're using some Rails-fu that is handling the key transformation for you. Standard JSON does *not* support Ruby Symbols as keys, so this is at least in part a problem with the way your application is serializing the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The provided string is not JSON, it is a string representation of a hash that can converted to a hash with

```
eval("{:address=>\"\", :city=>\"\", :country=>\"\", :zip=>\"\", :state=>\"\", :industry=>\"\", :org=>\"\", :job_title=>\"\", :purchasing_time_frame=>\"\", :role_in_purchase_process=>\"\", :no_of_employees=>\"\", :comments=>\"\", :custom_questions=>[{\"title\"=>\"License Number\", \"value\"=>\"345g3245\"}, {\"title\"=>\"License Type\", \"value\"=>\"Legal\"}], :create_time=>\"2022-01-17T22:49:26Z\"}")
```

Comment: Please don't worry about being new or inexperienced. We don't care. We only care about well asked questions and good answers. I'd recommend that you go through the tour to gain sufficient reputation to use comments also. Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).